# Java spring boot data entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping, entity, persistence

I am working on java spring boot application with spring tool suite and I follow a certain tutorial for entity mapping but am getting an error that says unknown entity of a thing. Here is the error from the console. I will really appreciate everyone's suggestions.

````
```
````

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Vehicle.inCharge references an unknown entity: com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Employee
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1750) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1694) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
... 16 common frames omitted
```

````
Here is my Employee class
    package com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
    import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
    import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
    
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
    import java.util.Date;
    
    @Entity
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
    @MappedSuperclass
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    
    public class Employee extends Person{
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="employeetypeid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private EmployeeType employeeType;
        private Integer employeetypeid;
        private String photo;
        private String username;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="jobtitleid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private JobTitle jobTitle;
        private Integer jobtitleid;
    
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date hireDate;
    
    }
```
   
And here is my Vehicle class
    
```java
    package com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model;
    
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Data;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
    
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.util.Date;
    
    @Entity
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
    
    public class Vehicle {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        private int id;
    
        private String name;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="vehicletypeid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private VehicleType vehicleType;
        private Integer vehicletypeid;
    
        private String vehicleNumber;
    
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date registrationDate;
    
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date acquisitionDate;
        private String description;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="vehiclemakeid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private VehicleMake vehicleMake;
        private Integer vehiclemakeid;
    
        private String power;
        private String fuelCapacity;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="vehiclestatusid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private VehicleStatus vehicleStatus;
        private Integer vehiclestatusid;
    
        private String netWeight;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="employeeid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private Employee inCharge;
        private Integer employeeid;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="vehiclemodelid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private VehicleModel vehicleModel;
        private Integer vehiclemodelid;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="locationid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
        private Location currentLocation;
        private Integer locationid;
    
        private String remarks;
    
    }
Employee class

package com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@MappedSuperclass
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")

public class Employee extends Person{

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employeetypeid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private EmployeeType employeeType;
    private Integer employeetypeid;
    private String photo;
    private String username;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="jobtitleid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private JobTitle jobTitle;
    private Integer jobtitleid;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date hireDate;

}
````

Comment: Please also provide your employee class. The Stacktrace indicates a problem there  references an unknown entity: com.elijahukeme.PropertiesManagementSystem.model.Employee

Comment: the Employee class was there already but I don't know why it wasn't showing. I have added it again @GJohannes